# Android Device Database

Tags: android

I am wondering if there are any android device databases around.

One of the apps I am working on now allows users to install an app on their devices. Once installed the application registers with a server. The device becomes tied to the user account at a website. In the website I would like to display an icon for each of the devices the user has associated with his account.

Ideally the icon would depict the actual device they have. An android device database would ideally allow me to get this picture (as it stands even trying to figure out if the device is a phone or a tablet is tricky and mostly guess work (look at screen res etc...). I have googled around and have not found anything.

Ideally the device database would expose a rest API which I could query to get information about my device (including icons etc).

I am thinking of building such a service as well as an app that could be used to extract device info and upload it to the device database (the website would allow users to tie images to devices).

I thought I should double check that it does not already exist.

Comment: I'm doubtful there is a unified database, but this is an interesting question.  I think it would be very useful if there was one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has a list of Android devices on their previous Nexus One website [here](http://www.google.com/phone/). The list is however pretty incomplete, and depending on your location certain phones might be hidden (you can change that with the drop-down box though). The list however is quite detailed, and includes a lot specification data about each device too.

Of course this does not replace some web service or a central database, but I think it is the closest you can get as of now. And if you plan to make a database yourself, it is probably a very good ressource to get information from.

Comment: Yep, I had seen that. The problem I have is how do I tie a device (from the info the device has access to) to a given entry on their site. If I do end up writing a device db I will probably include an adapter to scrape info off this site.

Comment: One other thing to note: that gallery only includes devices that come with the Android Market pre-installed. Depending on your location you may have devices that don't come with the Google bits baked in, and those may or may not be in that index.